# Android Class in MainActivity does not receive Broadcast from Alarm Manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to use Alarm Manager to send and receive a broadcast that will call a method to create a notification. I want the notification to be created even when app is closed. I created a class with this method that creates the alarm in Alarm Manager:

```
@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
public void qotd(String toast, int hour, int minute) {
            // for testing purposes
            Toast.makeText(mContext, (String.valueOf(hour) + " " + String.valueOf(minute)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // cancel other alarms first
            Intent alarmtocancel = new Intent(mContext, loadqotd.class);
            PendingIntent cancelIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1001, alarmtocancel, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(mContext.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.cancel(cancelIntent);
            cancelIntent.cancel();

            // create new alarm
            Intent alarmintent = new Intent(mContext, loadqotd.class);
            AlarmManager setam = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(mContext.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, alarmintent, 0);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            setam.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);            
}
```

This is the receiver, I placed it inside Main Activity:

```
public class loadqotd extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // testing purposes
        Toast.makeText(context, "received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, QuestionOfTheDay.class);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setContentTitle("Your Question of the Day is ready!")
                        .setContentText("Check out the question of today")
                        .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        int notid = 001;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notid, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

This is the manifest:

```
...
<application>
    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$loadqotd"></receiver>
</application>
...
```

I have done an Alarm Manager dump and found the broadcast inside. However, when alarm manager fires, loadqotd is never called, whether when the app is in the background or when in the app. Also, it is neither due to build error or runtime exception.

Comment: Any nested class used for an app component - like your `loadqotd` class - must be `public static`. I would also suggest following Java naming convention, and capitalize your class names.

Comment: try using a non-zero request code:
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, NON_ZERO_INTEGER, alarmintent, 0);

Comment: @MikeM. It seems that I get the error non-static method getSystemService(String) can not be referenced from static context

Comment: Call it on the `Context` passed into `onReceive()`. That is, `NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`. You could just make it a separate class file, btw, instead of a static nested class.

Comment: @Amir it didn't solve the problem anyway I already have the broadcast in alarmmanager I just didnt receive it

Comment: @MikeM. OK let me try

Comment: You sure your manifest is correct? We can't tell from that pared-down snippet. Also, I assume you're certain the alarm is firing when you expect, yeah?

Comment: Yah, no error when building. Its nested in application in manifest

Comment: Well, that doesn't necessarily mean it's correct. It's possible to have errors in the manifest that will build just fine.

Comment: Shall I move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121401/discussion-between-mike-m-and-zehata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a nested class as an app component - like the `loadqotd` class in your question - it must be `public static`. Alternatively, you could move that to a separate class file, and update the `name` in the manifest accordingly.

Either way you choose, you'll need to change a couple of things in the Receiver class. You'll need to call `getSystemService()` on the `Context` passed into the `onReceive()` method, since it was previously being called on the current `MainActivity` instance, which it will no longer have access to. Also, you'll need to qualify the `NOTIFICATION_SERVICE` constant.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

And, lastly, the `PendingIntent` for your alarm needs to be a broadcast `PendingIntent`, since you're broadcasting to a Receiver, not starting a `Service`. Change `getService()` to `getBroadcast()`.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, alarmintent, 0);
```